# SSRS Hiding Text in Footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

On my SSRS report I want to hide a page footer if none of the rows returned meet the condition where I need to show the footnote.  I have a list of names and on the report I add an asterisk to indicate a certain condition for that person.  For example:

Smith, Sally*

I have a footnote that says something along the lines of:
*Employee needs updated form on file

I am using the Visibility option of the Text Box Property to add an expression to hide the text in the textbox of the page footer if none of the employees  have an asterisk after their name.  (No sense in showing the footnote if it does not apply to anyone on the report.)

I've seen some examples here and thought this would work (setting false to not hide the text if an asterisk is appended to the name in the dataset):

```
=IIf(Fields!Name.Value.Contains("*"),False,True)
```

I don't get a syntax error but the footnote does not show no matter what I do with this expression or similar ones I have tried.  I saw one place that said you cannot use a expression to hide the text in a textbox in a page footer but could not confirm this is true.

Is it my syntax or that fact that one cannot hide text in a textbox on a page footer?  The option is not grayed out so it seems this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This formula doesn't lookup a results set. 
It only checks the first row: if the first row contains asterisk you will see footnote.

You can try to solve this for footer such way:

1. Create report variable "Has asterisk"
2. Create function at report code:

   Public Function CheckAsterisk(ByVal CheckString As String) As String
       If CheckString.Contains("*") Then
           Report.Variables!HasAsterisk.Value = True
       End If
       Return CheckString
   End Function
3. Call function from textbox where you display person name:

   =Code.CheckAsterisk(Fields!Name.Value)
4. Check report variable at footer

Comment: Thank you.  I am having trouble getting this to work because I am really a SQL developer and not that great with VB.  But this gives me an idea to perhaps set a variable in my SQL code that creates the dataset and then try to reference that variable in the Visibility option of the Text Box Property to determine when to show the footnote.